# How to fix error in eslint while type import?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint

Hi I have probleb with ESLINT setup, for my TS, expo, react-native project.

I have added TS, import type, and have 'parsing error' from standard.

[image]

my configs:

babel.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

and .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: false,
    es2021: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'standard-with-typescript'
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'], // Your TypeScript files extension

      // As mentioned in the comments, you should extend TypeScript plugins here,
      // instead of extending them outside the `overrides`.
      // If you don't want to extend any rules, you don't need an `extends` attribute.
      extends: [
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking'
      ],

      parserOptions: {
        project: ['./tsconfig.json'] // Specify it only for TypeScript files
      }
    }
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  rules: {
  }
}
```

What happened here and how can I remove that error in my VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error is given the way you are importing `FC` and it is not ESLINT related:

Please, try that approach:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface Props {
    message: string;
}

const MyComponent: FC<Props> = ({ message }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Welcome {message}</h1>
        </>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

References: [react-native-docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not yet on TypeScript 4.5,

1. `import { type Foo } from "bar"` is not a thing. It should be `import type { Foo } from "bar"`. See [the section of the TypeScript 3.8 release notes that introduced the "Type-Only Imports" feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) and the [TypeScript docs' section on "Importing Types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types)
2. You can't mix type-only imports and non-type-imports in the same import statement. Again, see [the section of the TypeScript 3.8 release notes that introduced the "Type-Only Imports" feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export):

   > If you’ve used Flow before, the syntax is fairly similar. One difference is that we’ve added a few restrictions to avoid code that might appear ambiguous.
   >
   > ```
   > // Is only 'Foo' a type? Or every declaration in the import?
   > // We just give an error because it's not clear.
   > import type Foo, { Bar, Baz } from "some-module";
   > //     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   > // error! A type-only import can specify a default import or named bindings, but not both.
   > ```

   You should separate the type-only imports and non-type-imports into *separate* import statements.

However, if you're on TypeScript 4.5 or later, this should be working for you:

This is a TypeScript lanugage feature described in [the v4.5 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names).

There was [mention that it would take time for other tooling to support the new syntax](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45998#pullrequestreview-763454769).

For babel, support should be there now: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/13799 and https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/13802.

I'm not sure about ESLint. There's a related issue ticket about exports here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3597